# how to set certain column unclickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a 20 columns in my table and I managed to get the rows in my table to be clickable. Is it possible to set the first column until the fifteenth to not clickable. Below is my code.

```
$('#cdcTracking-list tr td:not(:nth-child(1))').click( function () {
    //....rest of the another code
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, when dealing with a table where you want a click event on each cell, it's better to use a delegated event. This is because there will only be one event handler (which is on the table) instead of one handler for every `td` element.

Secondly, to achieve what you need you can inspect the `index()` of the clicked cell to determine its column. Try this:

```
$('#cdcTracking-list').on('click', 'td', function () {
    if ($(this).index() > 15) {
        // do something...
    }
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ygpd7ha5/)